# OE hacele "cloak" vs English hackle?

Tags: etymology, old-english

What is the semantic connection between OE hacele "cloak" and modern English [hackle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hackle) "An instrument with steel pins used to comb out flax or hemp"?

Answer (score 1):

All from the OED:

> **Cloak:** Etymology: < Old French cloke (13th cent. in Littré), cloque, cloche < medieval Latin cloca , clocca , cape worn by horsemen and travellers, the same word as cloke , cloche , bell, *so called from its shape*. Cloak is thus a doublet of clock n.1 (a timepiece)

The arrival in English is therefore direct.

---

> **Hackle** in this meaning of "cloak" is more complex and died out in Middle English
>
> **Hackle** n.1: Etymology: Cognate with Old Saxon hakul cloak, chasuble (Middle Low German -hakel in mishakel chasuble), Old High German hachul cloak, chasuble (Middle High German hachel cloak), Old Icelandic hǫkull priest's cope, Gothic hakuls cloak (all strong masculine), and also (with a different form of the suffix causing i-mutation of the stem vowel) Old Frisian hexil cloak (of uncertain stem class and gender), Old Icelandic hekla cowled or hooded frock (strong feminine)
>
> †**1. A cloak, a mantle, an outer garment. Obsolete except in mass-hackle n. at mass n.1 Compounds 2.**
>
> eOE   tr. Orosius Hist. (BL Add.) (1980) v. x. 124   *Þa sende him mon ane blace hacelan angean, him on bismer, for triumphan.*

It also came to have the idea of a covering

> **2. A covering or skin of any kind, esp. a snake's skin. Also in extended use. English regional in later use.**
>
> a1450   Castle Perseverance (1969) l. 2650   Þer wymmen arn are many wordys. Lete hem gone hoppyn wyth here hakle!
>
> 1892   M. C. F. Morris Yorks. Folk-talk 319   Hackle is the natural covering of any animal, the human skin..‘He's got a good hackle ov his back’.

And then a **protective** covering of straw

> **3.a. A conical straw cover used to protect a beehive from the weather. Now historical.**
>
> 1609   C. Butler Feminine Monarchie ii. sig. C1   *Swine..rubbing against the hives, and tearing the hacles*.
>
> 2014   K. Foy Life in Victorian Kitchen 32   *A cone-shaped cover, known as a ‘hackle’, was added in bad weather to deflect the rain.*
>
> **†b. A straw covering used to protect a wine bottle.** *Obsolete. rare.*
>
> †c. English regional (southern). **A straw covering for the apex of a rick.** *Obsolete. rare.*

There is a second noun "hackle" in English, and this is the current meaning and is unrelated to "cloak", etc.

> *Hackle 2*
>
> Etymology: Variant or alteration of **heckle** n., perhaps after hack v.1

> **Heckle** noun:
>
> Etymology: Either (i) < Middle Dutch hekele or its cognate Middle Low German hekele (see hatchel n.),
>
> **1.a. A tool for splitting and combing out flax, hemp, or (occasionally) other fibres, typically consisting of a board or bar set with sharp steel pins arranged in rows through which the fibres are drawn; such an instrument forming part of a hackling machine.** Also (rarely): a machine for hackling flax, hemp, etc. Cf.

Comment: As far as I can see, none. There are two spellings of OE verb for "to hack" depending on which variety of OE you chose:  haccian and hæccan --**Etymology** in Bosworth-Toller is: A. R. hackede; p : Chauc. hakke : O. Frs. (to-)hakkia : Dut. hakken to hew, chop : Dan. hakke to hack, hoe : Ger. hacken to chop, cleave.

Comment: One wonders whether this _hackle_ is related to the hackles on the back of your neck that rise when you're scared or excited. It's the same area of the body as a hood or mantle.

Comment: @JohnLawler The hackles in that sense are the same as the feathers on the neck of a bird that can be erected to indicate dominance, and thus the fur on an animal's (typically a dog's) shoulder that rise when it becomes aggressive or generally excited. Humans do not have these so the phrase is figurative. Hackle for the flax comb and the feathers are both first recorded in the late 15th century: it's hard to say which came first.